# Notepad++ regular expression for XML replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to replace following lines in `XML` file:

```
hashName="'Miecz Nieb. Wojownika+5IMiecz Nieb. Wojownika+5" name="Miecz Nieb. Wojownika+5"
```

As the above line is not correct, I want it to be replaced like this:

```
hashName="'Miecz Nieb. Wojownika+5'" name="Miecz Nieb. Wojownika+5"
```

(It should take the item name from the name="" attr!).

This is what I got at the moment, its not working as expected since it does remove my `name="..."` attribute.

Search for:

`hashName="(')(.*)"(.)name="(.*)"(.)/`

Replace with:

`hashName="'\4'" name="\4"`

Comment: [On parsing XML or HTML with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: You have a dot in your regex after the last quote, but since the final quote in the input is at the end, with nothing behind it, that won't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this simple example this is working

Search for

```
hashName="[^"]*"\s*name="([^"]*)"
```

and replace with

```
hashName="'\1'" name="\1"
```

If you don't want to capture or group characters, don't put brackets around it, therefor I removed most of them.

To avoid that too much is matched, e.g. if you have two "name" attributes in one row, I used `[^"]*` to do a non greedy matching.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
Search for: hashName=\".+\" name=\"(.+)\"
Replace with: hashName="'\1'" name="\1"
```